# Pointwise convergence and liminf

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

Convergence in measure is strictly weaker than pointwise convergence.

To see this, take $(X, \mathcal{A} , \mu)$ = $([0, 1], \mathcal{B}[0, 1], λ|[0,1])$ and set:

$u_n(x) := \textbf{1}_{[i2^{−k},(i+1)2^{−k}]}(x)$,        where $n = i + 2^k, 0\leq i < 2^k$.

This is a sequence of rectangular pulses of width $2^{−k}$ moving in $2^k$ steps through $[0, 1]$, jump back to $x = 0$, halve their width and start moving again. Obviously $u_n \longmapsto 0$ in measure.

What about the **pointwise convergence**?

The book is reasoning by saying that the liminf = 0 and limsup = 1, so the limit doesn't converge anywhere.
My doubt is on the **liminf**. Why should it be 0?

My reasoning was: fixing an x on the interval $[0,1]$, infinitely often there will be a rectangle that make my indicator function taking value 1.

But I don't know what to say on the liminf.

Comment: Please see the typesetting edits

Answer (score 1):

For any $x$ and any $k>1$ there is always an $i$ such that $[2^{k}x]\neq i, [2^{k}x]\neq i+1$. Let $n_k=i+2^{k}$. Then $x \notin [i2^{−k},(i+1)2^{−k}]$ so $u_{n_k}(x)=0$. Thus, infinitely many terms of the sequence $(u_n(x))$ are $0$ and this implies that $\lim \inf u_n(x)=0$.

Comment: But how can there be infinitely many terms = 0 if , infinitely often, there will be some 1?

Comment: @GabrielePillitteri Doesn't $\{0,1,0,1,0,1...\}$ have infinitely many $1$'s as well as infinitely many $0$'s?

Comment: Yes, that's why i was thinking that limsup could be 1 or 0. But I can't figure it out why liminf is zero

Comment: What do you know about lim sup of a  sequence of real numbers? Do you know that it is the smallest limit point of the sequence?

Comment: Yes, that's why the liminf is one. But I do not understand why infinitely many terms are 0, since, sometimes, there's some 1!

Comment: I have proved that infinitely many terms are $0$. My $n_k$'s are strictly increasing.